# Is there a plugin for vim C++ motions

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Is there a plugin with specific C++ motions?
Like

```
vif - visual inside function.
```

That could be very useful for some macros etc.

Comment: See this: https://github.com/libclang-vim/vim-textobj-clang

Comment: Perfect one, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the precise `vif`, I did post link + explanation on how to achieve this correctly (this is unfortunately not a trivial task) from vim on [vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7925/quick-search-limited-to-a-c-function/7942#7942).

Regarding the other possible motions, well there are general plugins to select parameters (I have this within lh-cpp, and I'm aware of one another solution at least), there are other plugins that help to select words within `camelCase` or `snake_case` identifiers, but they are not C++ specific.

What else are you specifically looking for?

Comment: That's actually the answer I was looking for ;-) I've been just thinking of an operation which would be much easier to me if I would have such operators.

Comment: If you need advanced things, the generic lh-dev, and the dedicated lh-cpp offer a few things through a very poorly documented API.